# OnAppplicationQuit() and Socket.io not working as intended on Windows

Tags: c#, node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I'm having trouble disconnectings Users from my server,
it seems that the content of the function is ignored on .exe build.
But when i quit the Play mode it's working perfectly fine.
I haven't find any Topic about this so i'm a bit helpless.

This is my OnApplicationQuit function :

```
 void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> data = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    PassInformation informationFromServer = GetComponent<PassInformation>();
    data["ID"] = informationFromServer.ID.ToString();
    socket.Emit("DISCONNECT", new JSONObject(data));
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger to see if `socket.Emit` is being called at all?

Comment: I found my problem ! Socket.io OnApplicationQuit() function exit the socket connection. In playmode my OnApplicationQuit() was executed before Socket.io 's one and it was inverted when i built the game.
Thanks

Comment: You might as well add your own answer, it could help others with similar circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem ! Socket.io OnApplicationQuit() function exit the socket connection. In playmode my OnApplicationQuit() was executed before Socket.io 's one and it was inverted when i built the game. Thanks